# how to create spring cas login link

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

I have Spring Security 3.0.3 with CAS. Some of my conf follows:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter" />
    <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/web/auth?logout" />
</security:http>

<bean id="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="${cas.app.url}/login"></property>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="${application.stack.hostname}/ctx/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
</bean>
```

If I access some of the secured content I get redirected to CAS login. After authentication I'm redirected back to the secure url I tried to access.

On every page I need to add "Log in" link that does the same thing. Where should this link point to? I tried ${cas.app.url}/login?service=${application.stack.hostname}/ctx/j_spring_cas_security_check but that does not seem to work.

Of course all the properties are replaced with appropriate full hostnames :)

Answer (score 0):

It can point to any URL matching the pattern `<security:intercept-url pattern="/*/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for you should just be able to point them to ${cas.app.url}/login. Leave out the service parameter. This will take them to the login page of your cas server which will authenticate them to all of your secure services.